# list assignment index out of range in python

Tags: python

i am making a simple substitution cipher in python. i want this program to go through the characters in a string, then add their number values to an array, but it give me this error:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):`
    `File "D:\py programs\simple cypher.py", line 39, in <module>`
    `x[i]=18`
    `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`
here is my code:

```
pt=raw_input('string to encrypt ')
x=[]
for i in range (0, len(pt)):
    if pt[i]=='a':
        x[i]=1
    elif pt[i]=='b':
        x[i]=2
    elif pt[i]=='c':
        x[i]=3
    elif pt[i]=='d':
        x[i]=4
    elif pt[i]=='e':
        x[i]=5
    elif pt[i]=='f':
        x[i]=6
    elif pt[i]=='g':
        x[i]=7
    elif pt[i]=='h':
        x[i]=8
    elif pt[i]=='i':
        x[i]=9
    elif pt[i]=='j':
        x[i]=10
    elif pt[i]=='k':
        x[i]=11
    elif pt[i]=='l':
        x[i]=12
    elif pt[i]=='m':
        x[i]=13
    elif pt[i]=='n':
        x[i]=14
    elif pt[i]=='o':
        x[i]=15
    elif pt[i]=='p':
        x[i]=16
    elif pt[i]=='q':
        x[i]=17
    elif pt[i]=='r':
        x[i]=18
    elif pt[i]=='s':
        x[i]=19
    elif pt[i]=='t':
        x[i]=20
    elif pt[i]=='u':
        x[i]=21
    elif pt[i]=='v':
        x[i]=22
    elif pt[i]=='w':
        x[i]=23
    elif pt[i]=='x':
        x[i]=24
    elif pt[i]=='y':
        x[i]=25
    elif pt[i]=='z':
        x[i]=26
    elif pt[i]==' ':
        x[i]='_'
print x
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

In Python you cannot assign to an index greater than the length of the list, so each of your `x[i] = ...` lines would cause this IndexError.

Instead you would need to change all of these to `x.append(...)`, which will add a new element to the end of the list.

Really though, your entire code could be refactored so that it is much shorter:

```
import string

pt = raw_input('string to encrypt ')
trans = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(string.lowercase, 1)}
trans[' '] = '_'
x = [trans[c] for c in pt if c in trans]
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

What you currently are trying to do is better written like this:

```
pt = raw_input('string to encrypt ')
x = [ord(i)-96 for i in pt]
```

If this really is what you need depends on what you intended to do next, but hopefully that takes you a bit further.

Comment: This does have slightly different behavior if `pt` includes characters other than lowercase letters.  Also this doesn't cover the `' '` to `'_'` mapping from the original code.

Comment: @F.J: Yeah, but I bet you that wasn't really intended, because that makes no sense. Why map everything to integers, except space? And yes, my version accepts any ascii character not just a-z.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

string.maketrans(from, to)
Return a translation table suitable for passing to translate(), that will map each character in from into the character at the same position in to; from and to must have the same length.

Assign the translated to a separate list possibly? If this is what your looking for...

```
input_alphabet="abcde"  
output_alphabet="12345"  
trantab = maketrans(input_alphabet,output_alphabet)  
text="translate abcdefg"  
print text.translate(trantab)
```

Comment: OP: that would work for letters before "j", but then i have to translate them to 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your list `x` is empty, so there is no `x[i]` to assign to: just as the error message says. Instead, use `x.append(...)`. Or define `x` as `x = [None] * len(pt)` so that there are slots to fill.

Of course, there are much, much simpler and shorter ways of doing what you're trying to do. Try a dictionary, or the `translate()` method of strings.

Answer (score -1):

The list is empty what you need is:

```
x.insert(i,1)
```

Which inserts the value `1` in index `i`

Comment: No, but I think `insert` shows the proper way of doing what he was intending to do. Whether or not the way he did it is the best way, now that's another story.